# Iterate through Groupby.unstack() items to make separate plots

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I have an dataframe called afplot:

```
apple_fplot = apple_f1.groupby(['Year','Domain Category'])['Value'].sum()
afplot = apple_fplot.unstack('Domain Category')
```

I now need to produce a plot for each column of afplot, and need to save each plot to a unique filename.

I've been trying to do this through a for loop, (I know thats inefficient) but can't seem to get it right.

```
for index, column in afplot.iteritems():
    plt.figure(index); afplot[column].plot(figsize=(12,6))
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Fungicide used / lb')
    plt.title('Amount of fungicides used on apples in the US')
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('C:/Users/User/Documents/Work/Year 3/Project/Plots/apple_fplot{}'.format(index))
```

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way, but the whole idea is to have the plot be reset each time it goes through the iteration, plotting *only* the next column's line plot, and then saves it to a new filename.

Comment: It may be worth noting that many of the columns contain NaN values, not sure if that is relevant or not though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `df.iteritems()` iterator returns (`column name`, `series`) pairs ([see docs])[1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html). So you can simplify:

```
for col, data in afplot.iteritems():
    ax = data.plot(title='Amount of fungicides used on apples in the US'))
    ax.set_ylabel('Fungicide used / lb')
    plt.gcf().savefig('C:/Users/User/Documents/Work/Year 3/Project/Plots/apple_fplot{}'.format(col))
    plt.close()
```

The `xlabel` should already be 'Year' as this seems to be the `name` of the `index`. `Legend` is `True` by default. See [additional plot parameters](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I wanted. I've been struggling a little adapting to using pandas, so thanks a bunch for the help (I'm in a situation where I have to learn python from scratch basically in a couple of months).

Comment: You're welcome, glad the answer helped. The SO community will most certainly make this a whole lot easier.

Comment: Added plt.close(), need to close the plot after each iteration.

Comment: Yeah, the best idea I've had this whole time was to actually sign up to SO so I can post my own questions instead of trying to funble my way through problems by patching together answers to other peoples questions - sometimes what I need just isn't covered in other people's questions.

Comment: You did not accept the answer - is there anything missing?

Comment: Sorry, just busy. I forgot. :/